# Fit exponential distribution with noise

Tags: exponential-function, least-squares, noise

I'm trying to fit an exponential with noise (which in this case is a constant $c$) like this one

$$y(x)=αe^{−αx}+c,$$

having $(x_i, y_i)$ values (So $α$ and $c$ are unknown and are the ones that I want to find out). Without noise I simply linearize the values and then I apply the Least Square Method, but with noise I have no idea how to do. Are there any formula to do it? Thank you.

Comment: You should put math expressions in dollar signs instead of ` sign.

Comment: So the exponent has the same "a" as the multiplier?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For two data points,
$y = ae^{-ax}+c$
and
$w = a e^{-av}+c$.

Subtracting,
$y-w
=a(e^{-ax}-e^{-av})
$.
If $v$ is a lot larger that $x$,
then
$y-w
\approx ae^{-ax}
$.
At this point,
the Lambert-W function
could be used
to determine $a$.
Then $c$ could be gotten.

This would give a set of
$a$ and $c$ values
which could be averaged
or looked at to see
how much they vary.